# encode dataframe with python using encoder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I 'am trying to encode a dataframe with LabelEncoder() before creating my machine learning model

here the code :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
# LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()

# apply "le.fit_transform"
df_encoded = data1.apply(le.fit_transform)
print(df_encoded)
print(le.classes_)
```

But I got this error :

```
TypeError: ("'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'", 'occurred at index SACC_MARKET_SEGMENT')
```

Anyone can help ùme to resolve this problem? tahnk you

Answer (score 1):

There can be a problem with type of your data. I don't know what's your desired data type, but you can try converting `data1` to string:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()

df_encoded = le.fit_transform(data1.astype(str))
print(df_encoded)
print(le.classes_)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes there are NaN missing values in this dataframe. I try you code but I got this error :` ValueError: bad input shape (266572, 11)`

Comment: that's because `LabelEncoder` needs 1D array. If you want to encode 2D array (like a DataFrame), try using `OrdinalEncoder` - works the same, but it's rather used to encode 2D stuff. All you have to do is take my code and replace `LabelEncoder` with `OrdinalEncoder`.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I got this error: `cannot import name 'OrdinalEncoder'`

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of `sklearn` and you don't have `OrdinalEncoder` available yet. Check your version: `print(sklearn.__version__)`. If it's smaller 0.20.2, then try to upgrade your sklearn package. If you use `pip` as package manager, try running this command in CMD: `pip install scikit-learn --upgrade`